# Get AnyObject from Dictionary

Tags: ios7, swift, ios8, xcode6

I found several questions on stackoverflow about this but none of them solve my issue.

I have a `Dictionary <String, AnyObject>` populated with different kind of objects (ints, strings, arrays).
When I want to get any value based on key, the only way I can is

```
    let lTitle: AnyObject? = content["title"]; // content is a Dictionary
    mTitleLabel.text = lTitle as String;
```

It looks horrible for me, but I tried hints from another stackoverflow's questions and they didn't work.

Does anyone know another shorter way to get `AnyObject` from `Dictionary` ?

**UPDATED**

It will work even this way `mTitleLabel.text = content["title"] as AnyObject? as String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine

```
mTitleLabel.text = content[ListCellContentKey.title]! as String;
```

Don't forget to check if dictionary's key returns a value otherwise it will crash when you'll try to force unwrapping

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mTitleLabel.text = content["title"] as? NSString
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the values in your dictionary to be AnyObject? Int, String and Array all conform to Any, but not AnyObject.

If you have Foundation classes imported into your project, Swift will sometimes translate Int into NSNumber, String into NSString and Array into NSArray instead of throwing an error. This is likely why you have to do the multistep cast if you want to go from AnyObject to String because you have to go through NSString then bridge it.

If you make your dictionary of type `[String:Any]` it becomes much cleaner.

```
var content: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["title":"myTitle"]
let lTitle = content["title"] as String
```